# Files.exists(path) is false but file.exists() is true

Tags: java

Why does this code return false?

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc");
Files.exists(path); // false!?
```

Even when I convert to it from a File (which exists):

```
File file = new File("C:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc");
file.exists(); // true!!!
Path path = file.toPath();
Files.exists(path); // still false!?
```

Comment: Does `Files.size(path);` throw an exception?  If it does, does that exception contain a meaningful message?

Comment: This works OK for me

Comment: `mkdir -p /mnt/c/aaa/bbb`   `touch /mnt/c/aaa/bbb/ccc`  `File file = new File("C:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc");
  System.out.println(file.exists()); // true
  Path path = file.toPath();
  System.out.println(Files.exists(path)); // true`

Comment: Is `C:\aaa\bbb\ccc` a symbolic link? What are the permissions on the file?  Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates this issue and verify that this still happens if there's no other code around this.  Post the complete code for the [mcve].

Comment: my mistake. I was using Iterator<Path> iterator = path.iterator(); to try to get the files in the directory and recursively calling my method. we can probably delete this post. sorry. [Jim Garrison's answer might be useful for some people though]

Answer (score 5):

I was able to reproduce this under the following specific circumstances:

1. The OS is Windows (implied by the path syntax)
2. The path refers to a directory
3. The directory is read-only or, the user does not have "List Folder Contents" permission.

I tested this on Linux (Centos 6) and cannot reproduce it even when changing the filemode on the directory (i.e. `chmod -x /aaa/bbb/ccc` or `chmod -r /aaa/bbb/ccc`)

So this appears to occur only on Windows. There must be some difference between how `java.io` and `java.nio.file` implement existence testing with regards to file permissions on Windows.

Check the permissions on the directory.

This ***may*** be a bug worth reporting.

Comment: the problem was caused by my mistake. but to confirm, yeah, Windows, read-only directory. I'm not sure about how to change the "List Folder Contents" permissions. Thanks for investigating. upvoted.

Comment: Curiously on Linux with a read-only directory all the calls return `true` as expected.